# sqlcmd access denied on c:/

Tags: sqlcmd

I tried to execute a simple .sql script from the command prompt and this is the output I got

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -S {machine name}\SQLEXPRESS -i C:/SqlScripts/UpdateStat.sql
Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file C: (Reason: Access is denied).
```

I opened `cmd` under admin mode and got the same result. Checked C drive permission and Admin has full access.

Running on Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: Is this UpdateStat.sql the only affected script? Can you execute another script from this location?

Comment: Have you tried changing `C:/SqlScripts/UpdateStat.sql` to `C:\SqlScripts\UpdateStat.sql` ?

Comment: @McNets nope cant execute any of the scripts

Comment: @joanolo tried that, no luck

Comment: Could you try to add read/write permission to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user on c:\folder?

Comment: Move the file to a folder on your profile (My Documents) and try from that location...

Comment: solved it by adding a cd C:\SqlScripts first and then call -i UpdateStat.sql. This means the operation does indeed have enough permission and its just the c:/ part it doesn't like

Answer (score -1):

See length of the file and there should not be spaces in between file location string
Like the following
G: \SDCBackup12012022\NewDigiSignHstry.txt  there is a space between G: and \SDCBackup12012022\NewDigiSignHstry.txt
and
C:\Users\NIC2>
C:\Users\NIC2>sqlcmd -S NIC2-HP -d aplrran15New -i G:\SDCBackup12012022\apranNew
DigiSignHstry.sql -a 32767 -o G:
Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file G: (Reason: Acc
ess is denied).

pranNewDigiSignHstry.sql  reduced length to NewDigiSignHstry . it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).